# facebook share FB.ui popup window doesn't close

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, share, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the facebook  sdk to share an url it work but the popup doesn't close  I have this code to make that

```
<script>
       document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() 
         {
           if (!$('#register-sign').bootstrapValidator('validate').has('.has-error').length) 
             {
               if ($("#facebook")[0].checked)
                 {

                     FB.ui({
                        display: 'popup',
                        method:  'share',
                        href: '<?=$siteaddress?>/petition/<?=$id?>/<?=$title_sanitized?>',
                 }, function(response)
                 {

                      self.close();
                     //window.close();
                  });

                  //FB.UIServer._triggerDefault(post_id.id);
                 }

             }

         }
    </script>
```

Comment: why display: 'popup'?

Comment: the same thing if without display popup share dialog doesn't close

Comment: it should close automatically, there is no need to use self.close() if it works correctly...do you have a test link?

Comment: and without self.close doesn't close . just   FB.ui({
                        display: 'popup',
                        method:  'share',
                        href: '<?=$siteaddress?>/petition/<?=$id?>/<?=$title_sanitized?>',
                 }, function(response)
                 {}); doesn't work I seach in internet I retrieve self.close can work but...

Comment: works fine for me...

Comment: ok thanks , so may be the problem in  ID de l’APP Facebook